# iPad persistent second top bar

Tags: ios, ipad

I am designing a coperate iPad app. My app has 5 mini apps each completely separate in functionality, but all for the company.

I planned on having a full width top bar displaying the current mini-app name at the top, with a home button on the far left. This will be persistent throughout each mini-app. Then underneath have the custom app.

Each mini-app uses navigation bars, tab bars, and toolbars. So the above idea was my best guess on a way to go back to the home screen.

Would anyone recommend against this?

And, how can I make a persistent top bar?
I can come up with this part, but just in case someone knows the best way, I wanted to ask.
I was thinking of changing the frame for the navigation controller to start at y=20pt.

In the [Human Interface Guidelines: Brand Appropriately](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/UserExperience/Conceptual/MobileHIG/UEBestPractices/UEBestPractices.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40006556-CH20-SW29) it mentions having a second persistent top bar, but I don't know any other way.

Comment: The Human Interface Guidelines mention a second persistent bar at the top as an anti-pattern, as an example of how not to do it.

Comment: @Codo I know, that's why I posted this question. I wanted to know if there is a better way. I would say 99.9% of apps have 1 purpose, but my app has 5. (Client's request)

Comment: Why not create 5 apps with 1 purpose each? Switch between apps is easy on the iPad (four finger swipe).

Comment: @Coco I already have an iPhone version already made. At the top left of each mini app there is a 'Home' button. And it's by client's request, there can only be one.

Comment: Can you show screenshots how it looks like on the iphone? Put them on a public website if they're too large/many.

Comment: @ott I don't have a second top bar for the iPhone. It just uses the standard navigation controller. Where the root controller has 5 buttons on it.